# Is there a way to get the available currencies format using Google Sheets API v4?

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So, I want to format a column called `Cost` using a Custom Currency Symbol, let's say `New Zealand Dollar`.
[image]

I can do that using Google Sheets with the following steps

[image]
[image]

The question is how can I get all the available currencies and their formats using the Google Sheets API? I looked at the [guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_examples), but found nothing

Does anyone know about it?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for retrieving the prepared custom currency from Spreadsheet, while that can be set by [the number format](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) with the method of batchUpdate of Sheets API. I apologize I cannot propose the direct solution. As a workaround, for example, how about preparing a list of the number formats and using the custom currency from the list? If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, this was helpful, I wanted to make sure, that I am not missing anything. Thanks again for your response

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I apologize that your issue couldn't be directly resolved. I hope that such value be existing as the enum type. By the way, for other users who have the same issue, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting @Tanaike's comment as an answer here. Hopefully, others who are looking for the answer to the same question may find value.

```
Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for retrieving the prepared custom currency from Spreadsheet, while that can be set by the number format with the method of batchUpdate of Sheets API. I apologize I cannot propose the direct solution. As a workaround, for example, how about preparing a list of the number formats and using the custom currency from the list? If this was not the direction you want, I apologize. – Tanaike
```

Thank you @Tanaike once again